# CentOS6 Apache - Virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, centos6, web

I was trying to set up a virtual host in apache on my CentOS6 server that handles queries of a subdomain.

Let's say, I have the domain 'example.com'. Now, I want to create the sub domain test.example.com that serves another html page than the main domain.

I searched already for some instructions to do that, especially on apache.org and there were plenty of them, but no one worked.

The problem is: Whenever I visit test.example.com in my browser, I get the main page that is served by example.com althought DocumentRoot points to another directory.

I even tried this a minimal httpd configuration file containing nothing but the following code, but with no success.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/main
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/test
</VirtualHost>
```

Have you an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: PS: My apache server version is 2.2.15, build on Oct 16, 2014

Comment: Maybe you just have to refresh your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Change order, make `test.example.com` `VirtualHost` in front (before) `example.com` `VirtualHost`, follow by restarting `httpd` service.

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
 ServerName test.example.com
 DocumentRoot /www/test
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
 ServerName example.com
 DocumentRoot /www/main
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this did not work. When starting the httpd service I get the warning: "VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precendence". The first one was the test domain, but I still get the index file of the main domain.

Comment: you're missing something else; NameVirtualHost